# How does linux / netfilter / iptables "know" if a packet is meant for itself for to be forwarded

Tags: iptables, routing, tcp, udp

I have setup an ubuntu box as a router manually , using iptables + NAT.

But I was wondering, how does the "middle-router" know if the packet is meant for it or to be forwarded?

I tested this scenario:

```
                SYN                                       SYN
                src:192.168.3.3.8080                      src:12.12.12.12:8080
+--------------+dst:5.5.5.5:443       +-----------------+ dst:5.5.5.5:443
|              |                      |   Linux Router  |
|   Client     +--------------------->|                 +------------------>
|              |                      |LAN: 192.168.3.1 |
| 192.168.3.3  |                      |                 |
|              |<---------------------+WAN: 12.12.12.12 |<------------------
+--------------+SYN-ACK               +-----------------+ SYN-ACK
                src:5.5.5.5:443                           src:5.5.5.5:443
                dst:192.168.3.3:8080      (HOW???)        dst:12.12.12.12:8080

                                      Webserver listening
                                      on 0.0.0.0:8080
```

And it works as expected on the client. But when the router receives the packet with DST 12.12.12.12:8080 (on which it is listening) , how does it know to forward it? I tried this manually with UDP as well (so no TCP states) and it seems to work.

Why is there no port conflict when its the same port?

My iptables NAT rule on the router:

```
-A POSTROUTING -o enp6s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Why are you inferring the originating port to be 8080? On the outbound connection, the originating OS will use a high port as a source port, something in the 32768–60999 range.

Comment: What's the problem you experience? Questions just "out of curiosty" are better asked on SuperUser. That said, the answer to this one is simple, see the the [packet flow diagram](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg). For first packet in the connection, `nat` table is consulted and installs a record into `conntrack` table. For reply packets, the destination address change happens in `conntrack` handler, earlier than routing decision happens, so even if packet was mapped to the source port 8080 by the MASQERADE, the reply will reach original destination.

Comment: @MarcoZink I was able to set the originating port via netcat / curl and confirmed it via tcpdump

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov thanks, that is quite useful information. My apologies for asking on the wrong forum